# DBSet:ToList() works but DBSet:ToListAsync() not working? Why?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

The below works.

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<JobSeeker>> GetJobSeekersAsync()
{
    using (SeekerContext)
    {
        System.Collections.Generic.List<JobSeeker> jobSeekers = SeekerContext.JobSeekers.ToList();

        foreach (JobSeeker JobSeeker in SeekerContext.JobSeekers)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(JobSeeker.CompleteName.FirstName);
        }
    }

    System.Collections.Generic.List<JobSeeker> jobSeekers1 = null;
    using (SeekerContext)
    {
        jobSeekers1 = await SeekerContext.JobSeekers.ToListAsync();
    }
    return jobSeekers1;
}
```

However, when I comment out the first using(), then the following exception is thrown:

> JobSeekerContext::ctor ->3196068 Exception thrown:
>   'AutoMapper.AutoMapperMappingException' in AutoMapper.dll
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker:
>   Information: Executed action
>   JobSeekerMgmt.API.Controllers.JobSeekersController.GetJobSeekersAsync
>   (JobSeekerMgmt.API) in 4591.7411ms

Comment: Can you elaborate on what "does not work" means?

Comment: This exception is thrown: JobSeekerContext::ctor ->3196068
Exception thrown: 'AutoMapper.AutoMapperMappingException' in AutoMapper.dll
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker: Information: Executed action JobSeekerMgmt.API.Controllers.JobSeekersController.GetJobSeekersAsync (JobSeekerMgmt.API) in 4591.7411ms

Comment: What is the constructor of your context doing with AutoMapper?

Comment: @MikeLenart Okay, that's relevant content that should be included in your question. I've edited it into the question, but you'll need to give some context into how you're using AutoMapper (for instance, how are your profiles setup?).

Comment: Everything works if both using statements are used - some context class.  Mapper is not in my constructor.

Comment: The constructor is:        'code' public JobSeekerContext()
        {
            var serviceCollection = new ServiceCollection();
            serviceCollection.AddLogging(builder => builder
                                            .AddConsole()
                                            .AddFilter(DbLoggerCategory.Database.Command.Name, level => level == LogLevel.Trace));

            MyConsoleLoggerFactory = serviceCollection.BuildServiceProvider().GetService<ILoggerFactory>();
        } 'code'